# Checking multiple Radio buttons from different group boxes in c#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie in C# I just have a doubt.I have two group boxes,each of them has three radio buttons in it,If I want to select each radio button from each groupbox and write a condition for that ,,How can I do that. Below is the code:

```
   public void SaveMyTextBoxContents()
        {

            string path = usbLetter +"MSREAD.txt";

            if (lbItems.SelectedIndex == -1)

            {

                        if (rdBtnMed.Checked)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(filepath))
                            {
                                foreach (string item in lbItems.Items)
                                {
                                    saveAllText = medium + " " + item;
                                    outputFile.WriteLine(saveText);
                                }
                            }
                        }                        
}
                        else if (rdBtnMedium.Checked && rdBtnN.Checked)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(filepath))
                            {
                                foreach (string item in lbItems.Items)
                                {
                                    saveAllText = mediumNo + " " + item;
                                    outputFile.WriteLine(saveText);
                                }
                            }
                        }



}
}
```

Please help me I got stuck up with this.

Thanks Krik

Comment: Hello krik, excuse me.. but your statement isn't clear for me. What do you mean by selecting all the RadioButtons from each GroupBox? Do you mean iterating over each combination possible. (Taken those RadioButtons in each GroupBox can't all be checked at the same time). And I just can't make sense for "write a condition for that". I guess you want to do something different for each combination, is it?

Comment: Hii Theraot & bemused, Thanks a lot for the quick reply.I have placed three radio buttons in each groupbox.Radio button from each groupbox has been checked. I need to add the string "medNo" to the string "saveText" which is not working.I am iteration it through a loop. I assume that,I had done a mistake in grouping the RadioBoxes.After dragging the RadioButtons into the groupbox do we need to change the the properties of the groupbox, inorder to make them act like a group.

Comment: Check list: Did you initialize medNo? is lbItems empty? is saveText a string? is filePath correct? May be code doesn't execute because of a flow control we can't see? Are you getting an exception (which line)? [Suggestion: try refactor this to another method]

Comment: krik, is that it's evaluating rdBtnMed.Checked && rdBtnN.Checked to false? as bemused said "If rdBtnMed and rbBtnN are in separate group boxes then you should be fine". Otherwise the problem is somewhere esle.

Comment: I had set a break point and checked,It is not coming to the elseif statement at all.
I had another if statement which checks radBtnMed and it is saving the medium value into "saveText"  and it is not looping to else if (rdBtnMed.Checked && rdBtnN.Checked)
I had initialised the medNo and the lbItems is not empty.Yes saveText is a string and the filepath is correct , since it saves the string in radMedium correctly.I updated function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're brackets are off, so it only checks rdBtnMedium and rdBtnN if lblItems.SelectedIndex != 1. Here's what I think you need:

```
if (lbItems.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    if (rdBtnMed.Checked)
    {
        using (StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            foreach (string item in lbItems.Items)
            {
                 saveAllText = medium + " " + item;
                 outputFile.WriteLine(saveText);
            }
        }
    }                        
    else if (rdBtnMedium.Checked && rdBtnN.Checked)
    {
        using (StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            foreach (string item in lbItems.Items)
            {
                saveAllText = mediumNo + " " + item;
                outputFile.WriteLine(saveText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make small panels to the size of radio button pairs and place those radio buttons on them (two each). E.g separate for male, female; separate for young, old etc. The panel won't show on run. This will work Insha'Allah in a group box too.